# A use-case for r-value members

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I've discovered an interesting piece of code and I wonder if it is UB or not? At least, according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) it should not be. Is it a valid case for using an r-value reference?

> The lifetime of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a const lvalue reference or to an rvalue reference...

Something similar was discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774420/use-of-rvalue-reference-members), but it does not fully address my case.

```
template <typename T>
class ResourceLocator {
public:
    static void load(ResourceLocator<T>&& instance) {
        instance_ = std::move(instance);
    }

protected:
    static ResourceLocator<T>&& instance_;
    // static ResourceLocator<T>& instance_; // does not extend lifetime
    // static const ResourceLocator<T>&& instance_; // const is too limiting
```

Comment: No, such usage does not extend lifetime. The lifetime is only extended in the most straightforward case, like `{ const t& x = getX(); ... }` here lifetime is extended until end of block.

Comment: References must be bound at initialization. Assigning to `instance_ ` assigns to the (non-existent) object that it references. Also, if you pass a temporary to `load`, it is bound to the argument, and its lifetime only lasts as long as that argument's – until the function returns.

Comment: A lifetime of a temporary might be extended, but you don't have a temporary. You just have an r-reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** This won't work the way you want it to. It likely won't be UB though, as long as `instance_` references something that lives long enough to support an `operator=(...)` call from `load(...)`.

#### Explanation

References of any kind, whether rvalue or lvalue, cannot be rebound once initialized, and cannot be left uninitialized. Fundamentally what you're wanting here *cannot work* using references.

The static `instance_` will have to have already been initialized to some value on program startup, which would make:

```cpp
instance_ = std::move(instance);
```

assign to the object that `instance_` originally references, meaning this uses the assignment operator `operator=` for the `ServiceLocator<T>`, rather than rebinding the reference.

Even if it *could* work, RValues can only extend lifetimes to the natural scope where its initialized (as if they are object-values), and can only extend the lifetime when initialized with a  *true temporary object* (e.g. a PR-value, such as a `T()` expression or the result of a function returning a by-value object).

So even if rebinding was possible, this extension would not apply since the parameters are not producing temporary expressions.

#### Possible Alternative

If you're wanting to create a locator of an object that is immovable/uncopyable, maybe consider either using `std::optional` or `std::unique_ptr` to allow for a null-state, and offer an `emplace`-like function to construct it in-place. Such as:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class ResourceLocator {
public:
    template <typename...Args>
    static void emplace(Args&&...args) {
        instance_.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
private:
    static std::optional<ResourceLocator<T>> instance_;
};
```

Or, better yet, **just don't use resource locators**. They're just singletons pretending to be an abstraction, but they're just as evil.

Comment: you cannot rebind `instance_` from `static load` (and create dangling ref from that) afaict OP's code actually move assign the object.

Comment: You know, I completely overlooked that fact. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @ Human-Compiler this is probably not UB then, it's still not what OP want anyway (at least not in the sense of extend lifetime)

Comment: @appleapple Right, forgot to update that part -- thanks again. I probably should have taken more time to think about my answer first. Fixed. I originally head it in my head that the assignment in question was `static auto&& instance_ = ...` which completely changed the meaning and my answer.

Comment: Like Human-Compiler I completely missed the fact that this reference is initialized once in cpp-file (not shown here) and later the same object is reused via operator=.